# Make invisible an element located in a row of a ListView

Tags: android, xml, sqlite, listview

I need to make invisible a TextView located in a row of a ListView.
The ListView is created by a Database. I would like that the TextView with an Id (day0, day1, day2…, day7) could become visible or invisible depending on what the database tells.

In particular i can’t put in a Textview variable the elements with these ids (day0, day1, day2…, day7)

I tried this code to verify if all the elements with these ids became invisible but it doesn’t work.

```
TextView tx = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.day0);
tx.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:showDividers="none"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:showDividers="none"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
>
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:text="12"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_display_3"/>
        <Space
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_display_3"

            />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minute"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_display_3"

            />
  </LinearLayout>
  <Switch
      android:id="@+id/switch2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/days"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cacca"
        style="@style/AlarmDayToggle"
        android:text="LUN"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day1"
        style="@style/AlarmDayToggle"
        android:text="MAR"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day2"
        style="@style/AlarmDayToggle"
        android:text="MER"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day3"
        style="@style/AlarmDayToggle"
        android:text="GIO"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day4"
        style="@style/AlarmDayToggle"
        android:text="VEN"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day5"
        style="@style/AlarmDayToggle"
        android:text="SAB" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day6"
        style="@style/AlarmDayToggle"
        android:text="DOM"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity.java

```
    public class AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        //clean all data
        dbHelper.deleteAllAlarm();
        //add some data
        dbHelper.insertSomeAlarm();

        //Generate listView from sqlite database
        displayListView();
    }

    private void displayListView(){
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllAlarm();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                DbAdapter.COLUMN_HOUR,
                DbAdapter.COLUMN_MINUTES
        };
        Log.d("column", cursor.toString());

        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.hour,
                R.id.minute
        };

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

    }

}
```

DbAdapter.java

```
public class DbAdapter extends AndroidListViewCursorAdaptorActivity{

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALARMS + " ("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + COLUMN_HOUR + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_MINUTES + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_SUNDAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
            + COLUMN_MONDAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
            + COLUMN_TUESDAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
            + COLUMN_WEDNESDAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
            + COLUMN_THURSDAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
            + COLUMN_FRIDAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
            + COLUMN_SATURDAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";






public long createAlarm (String hours, String minutes,
                         Integer mon, Integer tue, Integer wed,
                         Integer thu, Integer fri, Integer sat,
                         Integer sun){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_HOUR, hours);
    values.put(COLUMN_MINUTES, minutes);
    values.put(COLUMN_MONDAY, mon);
    values.put(COLUMN_TUESDAY, tue);
    values.put(COLUMN_WEDNESDAY, wed);
    values.put(COLUMN_THURSDAY, thu);
    values.put(COLUMN_FRIDAY, fri);
    values.put(COLUMN_SATURDAY, sat);
    values.put(COLUMN_SUNDAY, sun);
    return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, values);

}


public Cursor fetchAllAlarm(){
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE,
            new String[] {COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_HOUR,COLUMN_MINUTES},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null){
        Log.d("fetchalarm","fetchalarm");
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public void insertSomeAlarm(){
    Log.d("insert","insert");
    createAlarm("12","30",1,1,1,1,1,0,0);
    createAlarm("13","01",0,0,0,0,0,1,1);
    createAlarm("15","00",1,0,1,0,1,0,1);
    createAlarm("16","00",1,0,1,1,1,0,0);
    createAlarm("17","00",0,1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

}

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you dont have an id with `day0`. Doesn't that code crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to manipulate the views within a list you need to use a customised adapter by extending a suitable adapter.

First though you need to provided the adapter with the values so I'd suggest providing a method that creates a Cursor with all columns rather than a subset of the available columns as your `fetchAllAlarm` method provides. Something along the lines of :-

```
public Cursor getAllAlarms() {
    return mDb.query(TABLE_ALARMS,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Now create a class for your Custom Adapter e.g ALarmCursorAdpater that extends the SimpleCursorAdapter. e.g. :-

```
public class AlarmCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

}
```

Add the/a constructor e.g :-

public class AlarmCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

```
AlarmCursorAdapter(Context context,
                   int layout,
                   Cursor csr, String[] columns, int[] toviews) {
    super(context, layout,csr,columns,toviews,0);
}
```

}

Note! that in the above I haven't allowed the option to specify the flags (6th) parameter, rather it is hard coded when calling super.

Now it's a matter of implementing the customisation by overriding appropriate methods. There are two such methods that can be helpful in this situation **`bindView`** and **`getView`**.

**`bindView`** attaches the data (as per the columns provided) to the view (as per the views provide). The method is passed the Cursor, which will be appropriately positioned (i.e at the row for which the view is being built).

**`getView`** gets the appropriate view. The method is passed the position, the view and it's parent and must return the view.

The most appropriate of the two for acting upon the data is the **`bindView`** method as it provides the Cursor, so it is easy to act upon the data within the Cursor.

Anyway at first this is the CustomAdapter with overrides for the **`bindView`** and **`getView`** methods that will change nothing (i.e. it just calls the super methods):-

```
public class AlarmCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    AlarmCursorAdapter(Context context,
                       int layout,
                       Cursor csr, String[] columns, int[] toviews) {
        super(context, layout,csr,columns,toviews,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor csr) {
        super.bindView(view, context, csr);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertview, parent);
    }
}
```

Now assuming that you want to make a day invisible if it's value is 0 and to otherwise make it visible, then two things are needed a) determination of the state of the data accordingly and b) the View (TextView) to be adjusted.

- As the Cursor is available the appropriate Cursor `get????` methods can be used to obtain the data.
- As the View (not the specific view for the data, but the view for the ListView item) is provided. The specific views for the data can be obtained using findViewById.

So the adapter could become :-

```
public class AlarmCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    AlarmCursorAdapter(Context context,
                       int layout,
                       Cursor csr, String[] columns, int[] toviews) {
        super(context, layout,csr,columns,toviews,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor csr) {
        TextView monday = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.day1);
        if (csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.COLUMN_MONDAY)) > 0) {
            monday.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            monday.setBackgroundColor(0xFFCCCCFF);
        } else {
            monday.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertview, parent);
    }
}
```

So if the value in the monday column at the row being processed is greater than 0 then it's View will be made visible and for illustration purposes also have it's background colour set to light blue. Otherwise (i.e. if the data's value is 0 or less) then it will be invisible.

The custom adapter can now be used e.g. :-

```
private void displayAltListView() {
    Cursor csr = dbHelper.getAllAlarms();
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            DbAdapter.COLUMN_HOUR,
            DbAdapter.COLUMN_MINUTES,
    };
    int[] toviewids = new int[]{
            R.id.hour,
            R.id.minute
    };
    alarmAdapter = new AlarmCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.row,
            csr,
            columns,
            toviewids
    );
    alarmlist.setAdapter(alarmAdapter);
}
```

To utilise the above you'd need a class variable called **`alarmAdapter`** for the CustomAdapter.

Note that I've in your code you didn't set the Listview's adapter nor did you retrieve the ListView from it's id. So if you copy the above then you would need:-

So you would have :-

```
DbAdapter dbHelper;
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
AlarmCursorAdapter alarmAdapter;
ListView alarmlist;
```

instead of :-

```
DbAdapter dbHelper;
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
```

You would also need the following line in the Activity's `onCreate` methdo after the contentView has been set view via the call to `setContentView` :-

```
alarmlist = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.alarm_listview);
```

The result would be along the lines of :-

[image]